# CMake: find_package() without installing the dependency

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake project. The structure is something like this:

```
SharedLib
- lib1
- lib2
```

Where `lib2` depends on `lib1`, in a way that in its CMakeLists.txt, it uses `find_package(lib1 REQUIRED)`. Both libs are static, and both the SharedLib and lib2 uses lib1.

The top-level CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_subdirectory("mypath/lib1" ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib1)
add_subdirectory("mypath/lib2" ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib2)
```

Now, `find_package()` fail in configure-time since `lib1` isn't compiled at this point, and not installed to a place, that cmake can find.

The question is, (how) can I make `find_package()` find my `lib1`, that is in the project, with source code.

---

*Note: if it's relevant, `lib1` is `zlib` and `lib2` is `libzip`*

Comment: not possible see:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17735

Comment: `fail in configure-time since lib1 isn't compiled at this point,` nothing is compiled at configure time. `how) can I make find_package() find my lib1, that is in the project, with source code.` you have to compile lib1, and install lib1 to your chosen location, separately of cmake. before running it at all. Then do `find_package(lib1 PATHS the/path/you/installed/lib1/to)`. `find_package` is for finding external stuff, installed externally of cmake, way before it. `add_subdirectory("mypath/lib1"` Then why do you want to `find_package` it?

Comment: >Then why do you want to find_package it?
i don't, the lib2 (ziplib) came with that, and i want to compile it without installing zlib, and i hoped that i didnt have to modify the lib's cmake